# If i have to print from javascript then window.print() is the only way i have?

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I am trying to print a text using *javascript*. I have searched n number of times like 'How to print using javascript?' the only way I can do it is `window.print()`. Is this the only way?? Or Is there any other way?? 
for example: Using jquery or something else?

Comment: did any of the answers solve your problem ?

Comment: Why on earth this is down voted.. just because i did not accept any answer.. ?? This is not a lame question.. @thisOneGuy yeah your answer satisfied my question i will wait few more hours before accepting your answer.. I am waiting for someone who may provide an answer with something like a jquery print plugin(i don't know if this exists)...

Comment: why would you need a plugin ? It's 2 lines of code :/ What is it exactly you want to do ?

Comment: I am trying to print a barcode.. I have print information like '^XA^LH0,20^LL1...' and I want to invoke a printer from the browser itself by passing the printer information as input.. BTW mine is ZEBRA printer... as your answer is correct for the asked question I am accepting your answer. .

Comment: Yeah, I was going to say. Perhaps you should ask a more precise question of exactly what you want to happen, then you would get a more precise answer :) Let me know if you do and I'll take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log(insert string here);
```

Above logs the string (text) to the console window (ctrl + shift + I, in Chrome).

Unless you actually mean print the text off from a printer.

This prints whole window :

```
     document.getElementById('printEverything').addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        window.print();}

//or JQuery

     $('.printEverything').click(function(){
        window.print();});
```

This prints selected area:

```
        document.getElementById('printCertainArea').addEventListener("click", function (event) {
             document.getElementById('selectedArea').print();
        }

//or JQuery

    $('.printCertainArea').click(function(){
         $("#outprint").print();
    });
```

Comment: Copy-pasted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456717/how-can-i-print-using-jquery

Comment: @CzechErface ive flagged as duplicate

Comment: @thisOneGuy ah sorry, didn't notice that

Answer (score 0):

try also document.write() and console.log()

Answer (score 0):

To print output directly to your page you can do this:

```
<span id="ID" hidden>Enter you text here</span>
```

And when you want to show it use jQuery

```
$("#ID").show();
```