# Iframe content is getting cut when using window.print()

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, iframe

I am using javascript `window.print()` for opening browser print. However when print view is opened, chart(which is in iframe) is getting cut of.. I tried some solutions but nothing work for me.

Button click

```
<a href="javascript:window.print();" class="tooltips mr15" title="Print Report">
    <div class="icon-print-lrg"></div>
</a>
```

Iframe html

```
<iframe id="kibana_url" src="{{reportsvm.kibanaUrl}}" style="min-height:600px; width:100%;" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

CSS class

```
@media print
{  
    .noPrint, .noPrint *
    {
        display: none !important;
    }   
}
```

I added in css zoom:200% because when browser is at 200% everything is good, but that is not working for me.

```
@media print
{ 
   iframe 
   {
    zoom: 200%;
   }
  .noPrint, .noPrint *
  {
  display: none !important;
  }        
}
```

Actual look:

https://snag.gy/iShT4D.jpg

Print look:

https://snag.gy/P0NhK2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried JQuery print function? Also i think in @media print if you reduce the zoom around 75% you will get the whole area. Also i found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456717/how-can-i-print-using-jquery)
here.